# In Jquery dialog buttons - on yes, how to redirect with captured ahref value?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of rows from mysql table, each contains : a href tag, whose value is varying based on id like : `href="123.php?id=sbsbd"`. I coded a jquery dialog, with 2 buttons - YES / NO. Upon, YES, I want to proceed with redirection request, from that particular `a href` link. Any guesses, how this can be done ?

```
    <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
      integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
      crossorigin="anonymous">

      </script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(e) {

      ////////////////////////// 001 //////////////////////////

      $("#proceed").dialog({

      autoOpen: false,
      buttons : {

      "Yes": function(){

      // stuck here
      // need to go to URL in ahref = "123.php?id=sbsbd";
      // id value keeps changing


      }, 
      "No": function(){

      $(this).dialog("close")

      }


      }


      });


      //////////////////////// 002 ///////////////////////////


      $("a").click(function(){

      //$("#proceed").css("display", "block !important");
      $("#proceed").dialog("open");

      return false; 

      });  // click-function ends
      });  //  document.ready function-ends

      </script>


      </head>

      <body>

      <a href="123.php?id=sbsbd">Click for confirmation!</a>

      <div id="proceed" title="Delete this Slide-Image" style="display:none">
      <p>Slide-Image will be deleted permanently from Homepage and from Server, too. Ok ?</p>
      </div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

Comment: haha..dear, its more about redirecting with captured parameters. I mentioned it.

Comment: try my answer dear

Answer (score 0):

create the global access variable and set the href value to that variable when on click and use it to redirect.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(e) {

          ////////////////////////// 001 //////////////////////////

          $("#proceed").dialog({

          autoOpen: false,
          buttons : {

          "Yes": function(){


           alert(url);
          window.location.href = url;
          //here you can use that variable 


          }, 
          "No": function(){

          $(this).dialog("close")

          }


          }


          });




          var url ='';

          $("a").click(function(){


          $("#proceed").dialog("open");

            url = $(this).attr('href');
            //asign the clicked url into this url variable 
          return false; 

          }); 
          });
          </script
```